# Is a list of values increasing?

Tags: c++, hyperlink, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to write a method that looks at a list of values, and determines true or false if they are increasing or not

For example, for a list containing head-() (11) (8) (15) (3), isIncreasing() should return false. However, it would return true when working on a list containing head- () (7) (9) (15).

I am finding myself increasingly frustrated with this problem, and it's really stumped me. If someone can piece together some code it would do wonders. As situations where I am wanting to look through each number of a set always gives me issues.

I began to write out the method with the signature

```
bool List<Object>::isIncreasing() const;
```

and from there I have no idea where to begin

Any help?

Thanks a ton

**EDIT
Implementation**

```
#ifndef LIST_CPP
#define LIST_CPP

#include "List.h"

namespace cs20 {
template <class Object>
List<Object>::List() {
    head = new ListNode<Object>;
}

template <class Object>
List<Object>::List( const List<Object>& rhs ) {
    head = new ListNode<Object>;
    *this = rhs;
}

template <class Object>
List<Object>::~List() {
    makeEmpty();
    delete head;
}

template <class Object>
bool List<Object>::isEmpty() const {
    return( head->nextIsNull() );
}

template <class Object>
void List<Object>::makeEmpty() {
    while (!isEmpty()) {
        remove( first().retrieve() );
    }
}

template <class Object>
ListIterator<Object> List<Object>::zeroth() const {
    return( ListIterator<Object>( head ) );
}

template <class Object>
ListIterator<Object> List<Object>::first() const {
    return( ListIterator<Object>( head->getNext() ) );
}

template <class Object>
void List<Object>::insert( const Object& data,
                           const ListIterator<Object> &iter ) {
    if (iter.isValid()) {
        ListNode<Object>* newnode = new ListNode<Object>( data, iter.current->getNext() );
        iter.current->setNext( newnode );
    }
}

template <class Object>
void List<Object>::insert( const Object& data ) {
    // insert after the header node
    ListNode<Object>* newnode = new ListNode<Object>( data, head->getNext() );
    head->setNext( newnode );
}

template <class Object>
ListIterator<Object> List<Object>::findPrevious( const Object& data ) const {
    ListNode<Object>* node = head;
    while( node->getNext() != NULL && node->getNext()->getElement() != data ) {
        node = node->getNext();
    }
    if (node->getNext() == NULL) {
        node = NULL;
    }
    return ListIterator<Object>( node );
}


template <class Object>
bool List<Object>::isIncreasing() const {


    }

template <class Object>
void List<Object>::insert_back( const Object& data ) {
    ListNode<Object>* newnode = new ListNode<Object>( data, NULL );
    ListNode<Object>* lastNode = head;
    while (lastNode->getNext()!= NULL && lastNode->getNext()->getElement() != data )
        lastNode = lastNode->getNext();
    lastNode->setNext( newnode );

}

template <class Object>
void List<Object>::remove( const Object& data ) {
    ListIterator<Object> iter = findPrevious( data );
    if (iter.isValid()) {
        ListNode<Object>* node = findPrevious( data ).current;
        if (node->getNext() != NULL) {
            ListNode<Object> *oldNode = node->getNext();
            node->setNext( node->getNext()->getNext() );  // Skip oldNode
            delete oldNode;
        }
    }
}

// Deep copy of linked list
template <class Object>
const List<Object>& List<Object>::operator =( const List<Object>& rhs ) {
    if (this != &rhs) {
        makeEmpty();

        ListIterator<Object> rightiter = rhs.first( );
        ListIterator<Object> myiterator = zeroth();
        while( rightiter.isValid() ) {
            insert( rightiter.retrieve(), myiterator );
            rightiter.advance();
            myiterator.advance();
        }
    }
    return( *this );
}

}

#endif
```

**EDIT 2
Below is an "output" of how the isIncreasing should work**

TESTING HINT:

Run the methods: insert( 3 ); insert( 2 ); insert( 1 );
Print the list. What should it look like?
Call: isIncreasing(); What should it return?
Print the list. What should it look like?
Run the methods: remove( 3 ); remove( 2 );
Print the list. What should it look like?
Call: isIncreasing(); What should it return?
Print the list. What should it look like?
Run the methods: remove( 1 );
Run the methods: insert( 7 ); insert( 9 ); insert( 11 );
Print the list. What should it look like?
Call: isIncreasing(); What should it return?
Print the list. What should it look like?

Comment: if this is homework please tag it as such

Comment: Is the list itself implemented by you or are you using a built-in type or library?

Comment: Can you show us your implementation of `List` and what you've tried so far? We'd be happy to help, but with just what you've posted we can't do anything to help out.

Comment: There will be a driver that will asks the user for values. The user can add or remove values. And then run isIncreasing to determine if the order of values in the list are increasing or not

Comment: @OmryYadan homework tag is now [deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)

Comment: A suggestion: implement a list, implement a function that takes the list and iterates over its element, checking whether an element is greater than the previous one. It doesn't make much sense for a list class to have an `IsIncreasing` method.

Comment: You could monitor the user input. If he inputs only numbers in increasing order you know the list will be increasing. Done.

Comment: @templatetypedef I've posted the implementation code. Most of the was provided for us. I added some of my own, such as insert_back, but the isIncreasing is really stumping me

Comment: Should a list in which two subsequent values are equal be considered 'increasing'?

Comment: This is a very easy task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (not tested):

```
template <class Object>
bool List<Object>::isIncreasing() const
{
    ListNode<Object>* node= head;
    while (node->getNext() != NULL)
    {
        // Check if the next element is smaller (or the same as )... if so return false.
        if (node->getNext()->getElement() <= node->getElement())
            return false;
        node = node->getNext();
    }
    // If we get here then all values are increasing
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Such a help!! Thank you

Totally get it now

Answer (score 1):

How about something like the following pseudo-code

```
int last_value = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();

for (current_node = list_head; current_node != nullptr; current_node = current_node->next)
{
    if (current_node->value > last_value)
    {
        last_value = current_node->value;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

return true;
```

Comment: I'm not really sure how to relate this to isIncreasing

Comment: @user2906082 If the current nodes value is not larger than the last value (i.e. the values are not increasing) then return false. Otherwise the whole loop will finish and all values are increasing so return true.

Answer (score 1):

Another pseudo code possibility:

```
node = GetHead();
while( node != End() )
{
    nodeBefore = node++;
    if( node != End() &&
        *nodeBefore >= *node )
    {
        break;
    }
}

if( Size() > 0 && node == End() )
{
    bIsAscending = true;
}
```